# Ajax call doesn't update link html and class

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have dashboard with several panels with info & management. So, I'm rewriting the entire code to made it more Async to work with Ajax calls. I have a several buttons with .is-ajax class. So when I click on it, JQuery send a request for the desired endpoint.

This is the HTML

```
<a class="button is-danger is-outlined is-fullwidth update-all is-ajax" data-endpoint="update/all" data-params="">
                    <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i></span> <span>Actualizar todo</span>
                </a>
```

This is the JS

```
$('.is-ajax').click(function () {
    $(this).addClass("is-loading");
    $.get("ajax/" + $(this).data("endpoint") + "?params=" + $(this).data("params"), function (data) {
        $(this).removeClass("is-loading");
        $(this).html(data);
    });
});
```

Why the response don't modify but button?

Comment: using "this" inside an anonymous async function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First confirm that the server returns the html you expect.  In your success callback, try to `console.log(data)` to have a look.

Then assign the element you want to modify to a variable that you can reference, instead of using `this`.

```
$('.is-ajax').click(function () {
    var elem = $(this);
    elem.addClass("is-loading");
    $.get("ajax/" + $(this).data("endpoint") + "?params=" + elem.data("params"), function (data) {
        elem.removeClass("is-loading");
        elem.html(data);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

uhmmm of course! sorry for the noob.
Is this the solution then?

```
$('.is-ajax').click(function () {
    var btn = $(this);
    btn.toggleClass("is-loading");
    $.get("ajax/" + $(this).data("endpoint") + "?params=" + $(this).data("params"), function (data) {
        btn.toggleClass("is-loading");
        btn.html(data);
    });
});
```